# Gatling scala gradle, HowTo set requestTimeout

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I'm using gatling gradle plugin and I'm trying to increase default timeout.

- https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/gradle_plugin/

This doesn't work.
I constantly get

```
> i.g.h.c.i.RequestTimeoutException: Request timeout to localhos     47 (94,00%)
t/127.0.0.1:8080 after 60000 ms
```

my gatling.conf is

```
gatling {
  core {

  http {
    pooledConnectionIdleTimeout = 600000       # Timeout in millis for a connection to stay idle in the pool
    requestTimeout = 1000000                    # Timeout in millis for performing an HTTP request
  }

  }
}
```

I tried to corrupt my gatling.conf and build ruins

```
/build/resources/gatling/gatling.conf: 8: Key 'qd  qw  qd  qd' may not be followed by token: 'core' (if you intended 'core' to be part of a key or string value, try enclosing the key or value in double quotes)
```

So gatling really tries to read my file but doesn't want to override setting.

Who knows how to override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration file is wrong.

Your file, properly formatted:

```
gatling {
  core {
    http {
      requestTimeout = 1000000
    }
  }
}
```

How it should be, like in the [documentation](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/main/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf):

```
gatling {
  core {
    # core options
  }
  http {
    requestTimeout = 1000000
  }
}
```